# make column nullable EF 6 Code first in production

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a web api application using sql server EF 6 code first approach and it's up and running.

Now for a table I want to make a column NULL.

From sql server database side I alter my table definition and able to make the column NULL.

But the class definition has `[Required]` attribute, which is the reason database save (with null value) still failing even I made database column NULL.

```
 [Required]
    [StringLength(512)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

I there any solution here?

I understand I need to remove `[Required]` attribute and this requires a code change. I am looking if some way without code change. this is production .

Answer (score 0):

Removing Required attribute

```
[StringLength(512)]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

Comment: I understand this. but this requires a code change. I am looking if some way without  code change. this is production

Comment: The other option is to tell EF to allow the column to be null:   modelBuilder.Entity<SomeObject>().Property(m => m.Name).IsOptional();

Comment: more explanation is required